# How to make a response on the web using MQTT and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, mqtt, iot, paho

I have an issue with MQTT lib ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1 ).

I want to have async and sync tasks for multiple requests, but it seems I cannot get around an issue to make a response on web, for requested url /mqtt when actual subscribed message is received, because on_message is a callback function.

```
@app.route('/mqtt', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
            client = mqtt.Client()
            client.on_connect = on_connect
            client.on_message = on_message
            test = on_message
            client.username_pw_set('x', 'x')
            client.connect("x", 1883, 60)
            client.subscribe("/message/1")

            client.loop_forever()

            # how do I get the message from callback function on_message and then stop loop_forever?
#I thought about: return msg but it doesn't work.


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    #how to pass this msg to the main function?


    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop loop_forever when get message, you can use `client.disconnect`

Sample code:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))
    client.disconnect() # disconnect when get message
```

To pass message to main function, you can simply use global variable. But my suggestion is to start another process for mqtt client, pass variables via shared memory. It's a lot of overhead for connecting to mqtt broker every time got a GET or POST .